# Triangular div css shadows

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm using css transforms to fold a triangular div onto another. I want to make the triangular div drop a shadow on the one below it so that the fold looks realistic. I tried different ways to apply the box shadow on the div, but it did not work the way I want it to.

Here is my code so far : http://jsfiddle.net/wgLcB/2/

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to achieve [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/wgLcB/3/)?

Comment: Hmmm. The thing with box shadows is that it leaves a slight trail and its visible on the sides (especially when we add more blur)...  Like this for instance -- http://jsfiddle.net/wgLcB/4/. I don't want that....